# How to execute a command with $variable that contains spaces?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, terminal

In my script I have this line:

```
[ -z "$(file $1 | grep '256')" ] && echo 256
```

If $1 contains spaces, then I get the error message

```
line 11: [: too many arguments
```

How can I properly quote this so that it is runs correctly?

UPDATE:
I pasted the line from my script incorrectly. The error message is correct for this line

```
[ -z $(file "$1" | grep '256') ] && echo 256
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double quote the `$1`:

```
[ -z "$(file "$1" | grep '256')" ] && echo 256
```

PS: The line you posted would not cause the error you're referring to. Either you copied the error from another version, or you have another misquoted line in your script.

Comment: It works. But I don't understand why. I would think that the quotes around $1 would act to negate the outer quotes. Do you have a link where I can find out more about this?

Comment: The context inside `$(...)` gets evaluated first, then the parent shell's quoting is processed.

Comment: "The context inside $(...) gets evaluated first" Ah that makes a lot more sense. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use double quotes around your variables. Always.

(Well, not always always. There are situations where you want the shell to perform word splitting on a value, but those are a small minority and not something you should expect to understand any time soon.)

However, what you are doing there can simply be replaced with

```
file "$1" | grep -o '256'
```

Shell quoting is a common FAQ; it's poorly understood, but not hard at all. See e.g. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes (Bash-specific, but generally applicable to the entire Bourne family of shells.)